# Выбрать из таблицы значение?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с полями product_id, key, value
Как выбрать из таблицы значения product_id где:
1) key = emkost AND value = 510 
2) key = tok AND value = 54

То есть, получить product_id товара, который подходит и по первому и по второму условия. Уникальный значений нет.

Собственно запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM `hukelUUkhydjem_ms2_product_options` 
WHERE `key` = 'emkost' AND value = 54 OR
`key` = 'tok' AND value = 510
GROUP BY product_id
```

Выдает мне 2 параметра, а мне нужно 1.

---

Пример таблицы

```
product_id key    value
515        emkost 510
515        tok    54
516        emkost 510
516        tok    56
```

В данном примере согласно запросу выше мы должны получить значение 515, так как оно подходит по двум параметрам. А 516 подходит только по одному.

Comment: Где Ваш SELECT, что в нем конкретно не получилось?

Comment: Извини за заголовок вопроса. Не знаю в какую сторону копать...

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Добавил свой запрос

Comment: Дело не в заголовке, а в том что есть подозрение, что задача элементарная и кто-то хочет халявы

Comment: Снимаю минус, теперь я думаю, что найдется масса народа, которая Вам подсажет, если нет вернусь вечером - сейчас время игры в хокккей

Comment: Нужно было сразу воткнуть в вопрос свой вариант решения - вернусь через 2 часа :)

Comment: А вообще пример таблицы и входных данных на http://sqlfiddle.com например вот так http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db4675  было бы неплохо иметь

Comment: Не забудьте "плюсануть" ответы, которые Вас устроили и отметить зеленой галочкой лучший из них

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вам нужно выполнение **любого** из двух условий, то нужно всего лишь правильно расставить скобки

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  product_id
FROM
  `product_options` 
WHERE
  (`key` = 'emkost' AND value = 510) OR
  (`key` = 'tok' AND value = 54)
```

Если же Вам нужно найти только те product_id, для которых выполняется **оба** условия, то немного сложнее

```
SELECT
  prod1.product_id
FROM
  `product_options` prod1
  LEFT JOIN `product_options` prod2 ON (
    prod1.product_id = prod2.product_id
  )
WHERE
  prod1.`key` = 'emkost' AND prod1.value = 510 AND
  prod2.`key` = 'tok' AND prod2.value = 54
```

Ну и тест http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f274c/4

Comment: на сколько я понимаю оба варианта неверные....первый - потому что не для любого из........ второй - потому что нужно попарно, а у вас значения в итоге могут быть в любых ячейках... то есть просто быть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не понял про `попарно`

Comment: грубо говоря в таблице на одной строчке должно быть key = emkost AND value = 510 аналогично  key = tok AND value = 54......а в данной выборке это будет не так

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Читаю исходный пост `Как выбрать из таблицы значения product_id`. Т.е. ТС хочет достать **одно** число

Comment: Всё верно, где совпадут **обе пары** для product_id

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Так все работает http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f274c/4 Только числа перепутал в ответе

Comment: Да, я что-то джойн не увидел и выборку из доп таблицы :D

Comment: Спасибо. Второй вариант, где выполняются "оба" условия подходит.

Comment: А если мне понадобится добавить 3 и 4 условие?

Comment: @Дмитрий Добавляете еще джойнов или пересматриваете формат хранения

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Спасибо)) Я бы с радостью пересмотрел формат хранения)) Только нет возможности. Половину проекта придется переписать...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно как-то так:

```
SELECT `product_id`
FROM (SELECT  `product_id`, COUNT(1) AS `cnt`
      FROM    `table`
      WHERE   (`key`, `value`) IN (('emkost', 510), ('tok', 54)) 
      GROUP BY `product_id`
) tmp
WHERE tmp.cnt > 1
```

Comment: В MySQL в версии 5.1.45 была бага, когда применение `ROW()` заставляло сервер забить на индексы. Не знаю, исправили ее или нет

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ну я надеюсь в, уже 2018, никто не использует MySQL 5.1.45, которая была выпущена 10 лет назад

Comment: Просто я не уверен, что багу исправили

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `hukelUUkhydjem_ms2_product_options` 
WHERE (`key` = 'emkost' AND value = 54) OR
(`key` = 'tok' AND value = 510)
GROUP BY product_id
```

можно ещё поставить LIMIT 1, если строго 1 ответ нужен, а так скобки в данном запросе все решают

Comment: Данный запрос возвращает варианты, где выполнятся первое условие или второе. А мне нужно получить product_id у которого выполняются оба условия

Answer (score -1):

Лучше  делать так, например.

```
$myinfopost = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post p, comment c WHERE p.idUser = c.id");
```

Или почитай про JOIN sql